# I added `Marcos Melis Filehelpers` via Nuget and I am getting a warning which I don't understand, what does it mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, filehelpers

Basically I added Marcos Meli's FileHelpers to my Visual Studio Project and I am getting the following warning:

> A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'x:\y\packages\FileHelpers.2.0.0.0\lib\Interop.Excel.dll' because of an indirect reference to that assembly created by assembly 'x:\y\packages\FileHelpers.2.0.0.0\lib\FileHelpers.ExcelStorage.dll'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly.

What does this mean and what do I need to do (if anything, it's only a warning, not an error) to fix it? I am using resharper, I am not sure if this is a resharper warning or a Visual Studio warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182188.aspx):

> You have added a reference to an assembly (assembly1) that has the
>   Embed Interop Types property set to True. This instructs the compiler
>   to embed interop type information from that assembly. However, the
>   compiler cannot embed interop type information from that assembly
>   because another assembly that you have referenced (assembly2) also
>   references that assembly (assembly1) and has the Embed Interop Types
>   property set to False.

To get rid of the warning, find the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference in solution explorer. Right-click and look at the Properties.  There will be one called Embed Interop and it will be set to true - set it to false and the warnings will go away.